# AngularJS downloads PHP files instead of showing them, what's missing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to develop an AngularJS app but I have this problem. I want to access a database through the app but instead of loading the php file, it downloads it. Even if I access directly to the file (mydomain.com:8000/app/file.php), it's being downloaded.

If I try to access from outside Angular, that same file (mydomain.com/appname/app/file.php), loads correctly: it access a database and retrieves data.

So, what am I missing? do I need anything aditional? I was firstly basing this test project from the Angular Phonecatt App that AngularJs has as basic tutorial, then I read other tutorials about database access.

This is the controller code:

```
'use strict';

var cashewApp = angular.module('cashewApp', []);

cashewApp.controller('categoriesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('file.php').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.categories = data;
    });
}]);
```

And my php file code:

```
<?php
    $db_name  = 'db_name';
    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $username = 'user';
    $password = 'pass';

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM Categories';

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    echo json_encode( $result );
?>
```

I've tried this locally and remotely, both setups work fine without the php part, I see no errors when starting the server, so I have no clue.

Thanks in advance!

---

After modifying the ports.conf file like this and restarting apache:

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80
Listen 8000

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Angular doesn't work.

Comment: If it is downloading it, then the server isn't running PHP. I had this problem when I made an app and was using `grunt serve` to display it. What are you using as the web server?

Comment: Probable something to deal with your web server misunderstanding some HTTP headers (angular $http would maybe add a "ask for download" header when the path of the ressource contains a dotted extension, probably something like a `content-disposition` one). It would be worth dumping both manual and angular's HTTP request to compare them. See `tcp_dump`

Comment: Pretty sure it's because PHP isn't running on port 8000. It works on `mydomain.com/appname/app/file.php` because it's running on port 80

Comment: Ronnie is right. You should add `8000` as a "listen" port if you're using apache.

Comment: Thanks @Ronnie and Cyril, where are those ports? I see: "Listen 80" on /etc/apache2/ports.conf, is that where it should be?

Comment: I think the file you're looking for would be `httpd.conf` and you could just add a `Listen 8000` under the `Listen 80`. I've never done it, but you could try that. Be sure to restart apache after you change it

Comment: maybe this will help in setting up the ports correctly http://serverfault.com/questions/28041/how-do-i-make-apache-web-server-listen-on-two-different-ports

Comment: @Ronnie didn't read your other comment. Newest versions of apache don't have httpd.conf file, I already search for it and I can't find it. After a little research it says that that file is not longer used.